# Is it safe to keep Credentials likes Username and password in swift file

Tags: ios, swift, security

In my iOS app i'm using a web service that have some username and password for accessing the endpoints. For now I've kept the username and password of the web service inside my swift file and when i need to use the web service, i'm reading the credentails from swift file and sending to the web server. My question is Is it safe to keep credentials or any sensitive data in swift file? Is there any way to reverse engineer IPA file and read the credentials or any other way to get the stored keys on the swift file. As this is possible with android APKs where reverse engineering will expose the complete code to the attacker if saved in java file.

My swift file

```
class Connection:NSObject {
 ...
     public let pass = "AD%$^%DS78DS"
     public let user = "KKKSL"
 ...
}
```

Comment: 1. No.  2. Yes. You can easily get an ipa file and open it

Comment: thank you @Paulw11 .. can you please suggest some safe practices for this purpose?

Comment: Ideally the use would log in using OAuth in order to obtain a token to use the api. There is no really safe way to store hard coded credentials in an app.

Comment: Just now I was reading about using Keychain in swift. Will see if it will help.

Comment: But how do you get password into the keychain? If you are going to create a keychain item then the password already needs to be in your app somewhere

Comment: Use keychain to store sensitive information

Comment: There is absolutely no way to store information inside you app (or send it to your app) in a way that the information cannot be read by a user who has some skill. If you need to control, you need to authenticate the user, not the app. If you are accessing a 3rdparty system, you will need to route it through your own server. There is no way to reliably protect credentials that are known by the app, no matter how you store them. I've given a talk that includes some things you can do to slightly obscure information, but it is not strong protection. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziwm8bMKxsw

Answer (score 0):

Use the encryption algorithm. eg SH1

Comment: SHA-1 is NOT an encryption algo, it's a hash one.